# What are the chances to find a wild shiny Pokémon in XY & ORAS?

Tags: pokemon-x-y, pokemon-sixth-generation

I've been seeing people getting millions of shiny Pokémon in X & Y without effort. *My* first shiny on *Pokémon X* (Corsola) also took only 93 fishing encounters.

I'm wondering: is the chance of finding a shiny in *Pokémon X & Y* better than it used to be?

If so, what *is* the chance to find a wild shiny in *X & Y*? How does it compare to the previous games in the series)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[The chance of getting a shiny has indeed improved.](http://www.serebii.net/games/shiny.shtml) It has doubled. This is further increased by chain fishing, getting multiple Pokemon in a row without moving or getting the "Not even a nibble" message. Poke radar works much the same to improve the odds, and the Masuda Method of breeding further increases these odds.

The Masuda Method means you take a foreign Pokemon and breed it with one from your region. For example, say you wonder trade and get a Japanese Pikachu. Breed that with a Pikachu you caught and you have a better chance of a shiny than if you breed two Pikachu that you caught.

[This chance is increased further in the Friend Safari.](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Friend_Safari#Pok.C3.A9mon) In the Friend Safari, you are eight times more likely to find a shiny than the rest of the game. However, the shiny charm does not affect this.

Comment: @BenBrocka Thank you. I don't know how I got halved there. Might be that at first I thought that it in fact hadn't changed, before I double checked.

Comment: Thanks i got a japenese ditto so i can Masuda Method anything.

Comment: Same here. Easiest way to do it, though you get eggs faster if they're the same species.

Comment: Now I need to get a japenese Charmander

Comment: It's possible with the GTS now. You can get a lot of different-region Pokemon. It doesn't have to be Japanese. It could be German or Spanish. It'll show you on it's details, it'll have a little box representative of which region it's from if it's different. I know it's in the PC, not sure if it does it in party.

Comment: ive been fishing and i got 3 shinys(other than the mentioned corsola).i encountered shiny basculin but final gambit was used.then shiny poliwhirl which is now a poliwrath and was two days ago.then yesterday i found a shiny carvanha wich is now a sharpedo.then TODAY ABOUT 5 MINUTES AGO i found a shiny cubchu in a horde.

Comment: That's great! I'm glad you're finding them. I believe the hordes have an increased chance of shinies, but I don't remember where I saw that so don't quote me.

Comment: @ShinyCharmanderAllTheWay You wouldn't want to breed a Japanese Ditto with a Japanese Charmander. Having them both from the same region would cancel out the effect of the Masuda Method. If you have a Japanese Ditto, use it with everything that IS NOT from Japan. The 2 pokemon have to be from different regions for the Masuda Method to work correctly.

Answer (score 5):

The chances of getting a shiny are doubled in normal gameplay from 1/8192 to 1/4096. There are also many new ways to encounter shinies while retaining the old methods. The masuda method is probably the second easiest next to chain fishing. I'll discuss all the ways of catching shinies.

1:Pokeradar. The pokeradar has once again made a return to pokemon games and it is simple. you charge it by walking and you go into the patches of grass that are the same. You start a chain if you keep getting the same pokemon over and over again. you continue the chain by either capturing it or fainting it. If you run away, get a different pokemon, turn on your rollerblades, basically do anything other than encounter the previous pokemon---the chain breaks. however, if you get to 40 chains the chances rise to 1/200 and you can keep reseting the pokeradar until you get a shiny patch.

2:Horde. This is a very popular new way of getting shinies. All you do basically do is get a pokemon with sweet scent or if you have honey and keep getting hordes over and over again until you get a shiny.

3:Matsuda Method: Its basically what everyone said, you simply breed 2 pokemon from different regions and you hope for the best. O-powers and having a pokemon with flame body helps this method. This is ideal if you want to control its nature or iv's

4:Chain Fishing. This is also a new way of getting shinies and definitely the easiest. It's basically like pokeradar except that it takes a bit of skill. you have to consecutively reel in pokemon for a chain. the things that break this chain is missing a hook(like basically throwing in a rod but not getting a pokemon either b/c of mistake or simply didn't get a nibble), using wrong key item, moving, or opening any kind of menu. to address the not getting a nibble problem, I strongly suggest getting either a Inkay or Octillery with suction cups that ensures a nibble. I also reccomned not fishing from the shore and also fishing near rocks or anywhere that is closed off. This is the easiest b/c after only 40 chains, the chances go up to 1/200 and stays that way until you break the chain. Don't let this mislead you though b/c it is actually very hard to keep getting every bite. It also took me about 16 tries just to get to 40 and took me to 106 chains before I got my shiny Dragalge. I got my second one at around 167. The things that don't break the chain is running away, capturing it, and fainting it.

5:Friend Safari. The final and last way is very easy but very time consuming. all you basically do is just run around, derping until you get a shiny. This is good for competitive battling as friend safari usually gives the hidden abilities and good natures. It does have an increased shiny rate from the get-go. as soon as you go into one, the chances of getting a shiny goes up to 1/2000.

Hoped this helped you guys! ;)

Answer (score 1):

No one really knows whether the rate has increased or not. But by looking at the amount of shinies which has entered the game, through methods such as the Masuda Method and chain ishing, it's more than likely that once again, GameFreak has improved the chance of getting a shiny pokemon from Generation 5 to 6, as they did from Generation 4 to 5 (Masuda Method).

There also seems to be a higher chance of getting a shiny pokemon in friend safaris. No statistic has been confirmed yet, however.

Answer (score -2):

the chances go up when you are hatching the eggs but in the wild it is said the chances are now 2,192 for encountering a shiny pokemon. these are just rumors though but i have 2 shiny that were given to me and i have not encountered a shiny by myself. they were all given to me.

Comment: What source do you have that the shiny rate is increased in the wild?